# Patroni Haproxy and pg-bouncer

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer, patroni, haproxy

I'm building a Patroni Postgres cluster; however, I can't decide which is the better architecture:

- App > HAproxy > Pgbouncer > PostgreSQL (Patroni)
- App > PGBouncer > HAproxy > PostgreSQL (Patroni)

I can't seem to get an answer upon my search and a lot of conflicted answers. Some say it's better to have haproxy in front and others say the opposite.

The cluster is for 40 small to mid-size DBs. The goal is to serve them, and I don't have much control over them or their behavior.

Answer (score -1):

First option is what you want, because pgBouncer is a connection pooler for PostgreSQL. It needs to be close to DBMS and be one2one connected each one to its own Postgresql instance.
As for HAProxy it is a load balancer, you can have HAProxies' number different than a number of Postgre\Patroni\pgBouncer instances.
Plus it will give you an option to separate read and write requests to different ports\databases.

here is an article which will be helpful https://medium.com/@nicola.vitaly/setting-up-high-availability-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-pgbouncer-docker-consul-and-95c70445b1b1